# why @ syntax is not working in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaZavV
Hi

I am using `HOC` using decorator syntax .But it is not working why ? I make three component .But when I used '@' syntax above the component .It show nothing

```
 @D
    class A extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.update}>increase</button>
            <h1>{this.props.count}</h1>
            </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where have you seen `@` is recognisable in react?

Comment: Decorators are not part of React. Any JS language feature is not part of React. JSX is something React came up with but is not part of React either, it's a transform you apply to your code using a transpiler. Same applies to decorators, it's an _experimental_ language feature that you need to transpile.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are not available in the language, so you need to use Babel.

You could use [**babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy**](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) and add it as a plugin to your `.babelsrc` file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```